# LXQt Settings are not applied even on reboot - have always to edit config files - why?

Tags: lubuntu, 20.04, lxqt

**OS: Lubuntu 20.04**

I tried to make changes for keyboard and for battery management through the Lubuntu menu. Settings are stored in the menu window, but don't change at all any system settings, as for example, I set up Sleep Mode after closing the laptop, but it gives no effect. When I added a new keyboard to language settings, it had no effect too until I edited the config file of the system.

Should I always edit files? What are those settings in Lubuntu from menus if I can't use them?

Comment: Please mention your version of Lubuntu so that you can be guided appropriately.

Comment: Focal Fossa 20.04

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some bugs in LXQt.

I've been unable to configure sleep mode on my laptop, but I was able to configure Suspend mode:

**Menu** ->
 **Preferences** ->
  **LXQt settings** ->
   **Power Management** ->
    **Lid**

[image]

**Menu** ->
 **Preferences** ->
  **LXQt settings** ->
   **Keyboard and Mouse** ->
    **Keyboard Layout**

[image]

I've noticed, that my keyboard layout settings reset in case I run iBus Preferences (enabling daemon):

[image]
[image]
[image]

So I need to reconfigure keyboard layout using LXQt settings after that. After Keyboar Layout configuration I couldn't set <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to toggle layout, so I used **iBus Preferences** to reset it and configured it as it is necessary for me. After **iBus Preferences**'s reset + **Keyboard Layout** reconfiguration settings are applied.

**For hibernation** you could try to modify `/etc/default/grub`

```
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=2deb87ff-009d-4b6f-98b1-7c959dc54af0"
```

UUID you could find by executing commands:

```
lsblk
sudo blkid
```

Then `sudo update-grub`

It could also be required to create `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file with the next content:

```
RESUME=UUID=41e86209-3802-424b-9a9d-d7683142dab7
```

Then do `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Reboot, then use `lxqt-leave --hibernate` command to see what messages it displays.

Try to hibernate it directly: `systemctl hibernate`

If you could hibernate and resume without issues after `systemctl hibernate`, then we could go further.

In my case I don't use hibernation, so for testing I've [created](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1042946) `/hiberfile` and specified its `resume_offset` and root's partition UUID in `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` files. But in my case hibernation freezes my PC. After resuming it resumes correctly into freeze state, so I need to hard reset it. Maybe I'll resolve it, however I don't use it.

Comment: And so, what is the solution for Sleep Mode?